# Improving performance to assign class to x/y coordinates in python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, dictionary

I have following data using python 2.7.17:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
N = 600000
x = np.random.randint(1,160,N)
y = np.random.randint(1,160,N)
classes = np.random.randint(1,10,N)
data = np.append([x],[y],axis=0)
data = np.append(data,[classes],axis=0)
```

x/y are coordinates of a map and classes is a corresponding class to these coordinates.
x/y can appear more often with different class values.
I'm getting these data from a previous function.

I need to get one class per x/y coordinates. At the moment I'm counting the times the class is appearing per x/y. I take the class with the highest count. If there are equal counts, the higher class is assigned. I have done it with dictionaries see here:

```
data_zip = zip(zip(data[0],data[1]),data[2])
dic = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in data_zip:
    dic[k].append(v)
for k,v in dic.items():
    un,co = np.unique(v,return_counts=True)
    value = un[co.argmax()].max()
```

I need to speed up the process. Don't know how I can reach better performance.
I tried it with dict comprehension, using pandas instead of numpy.
What can I do to speed up the process?
Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the goal correctly, using Pandas core functions would probably be faster in this case.

The logic used is:

1.transform to get the count of each (x, y, class) combination;

2.sort by count, then by class to get the highest one in the top;

3.dropduplicates and leave only the top row of the combination.

Here goes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
N = 600000
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.random.randint(1,160,N)
df['y'] = np.random.randint(1,160,N)
df['classes'] = np.random.randint(1,10,N)

df['class_count'] = df.groupby(['x','y'])['classes'].transform('size')

df.sort_values(['class_count','classes'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(['x', 'y'], inplace=True)
```

Here is a smaple of the output:

```
            x   y   classes class_count
   2259     89  80  9       46
   14854    151 12  9       44
   35451    152 42  9       44
```

That means that the (89,80) point most frequent class is 9 (and it occured 46 times)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It is much faster. I know pandas not so well. So I tested it and getting an other solution than with my code. How does sort_values take the class with the highest count? Additonal when the counts are equal does it take the higher class?

Answer (score 0):

if the final array can be of different shape (last previous solution)
i think the fast approach is to use [numpy indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP)

```
import numpy as np
import numpy_indexed as npi
N = 600000
data = np.random.randint(1,160,(3, N))
data[2] = np.random.randint(1,10,N)
uniq_data = npi.group_by(data, axis=1).unique
```

This is pretty fast and full vectorial

Comment: Thank you @Glauco for this solution, It's faster but If i see this correct in uniq_data I'm getting all possible combination once back. Means if (1,1,10) as x/y/c apears 3 times i get it 1 time in the uniq_data and all other combinations too. I'm confused,how can I no aproach this and take frome the uniq_data the class which appears the moste?

Comment: i think npi.group_by(data, axis=1).count can solve.